# How to create .sfa snd .sfb file programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore

I want to convert `.obj` file to `.sfa` and `.sfb` file programmatically through code. Can someone help me out with that?

Please note: I do not need the code in Unity3D or Unreal Engine. I want the code in native Android (Java).

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/8). Currently there is no option to convert `.obj` to `.sfa` and `.sfb` files at runtime.

Only `glTF` and `glb` can be loaded at runtime without conversion: 
From [arcore documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables#load_3d_models_at_runtime):

> 3D models stored as glTF or glb files can be loaded at runtime without
>   conversion. This greatly improves the flexibility of the models
>   rendered in your application, but the trade-off is the model is read
>   at runtime and does not benefit from the optimization that is done
>   during build time conversion to sfb.